# Hide UIPickerView in UITableViewController while touch outside

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipickerview

Right now I have 2 different UIPickerView in side my UITableViewController. I only show them upon tapping of certain cells in the table. What I'm trying to do is to hide the pickers whenever I touch outside the pickers. Is there a delegate method or something similar to achieve this? I prefer to keep my controller as a UITableViewController instead of a simple UIViewController since I have a textView in one of the cells and scrolling after the keyboard shows is just a bit too much in a UIViewController.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I have the exact same problem. I know how I can solve this. I need to use the same concept as hiding a keyboard by changing the UIView to a UIcontrol to detect touches over it. For a pickerView its a pain in the ass to code it since there is a table behind it. I just put a done button on top and use [resignFirstResponder] for the IBAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Possible solutions is that when a particular cell is tapped and you handle picker (to present the picker), you can insert a view called as MASK View over the tableview. (with Frame as self.tableview.frame - yourPicker.frame.size.height ). Now when ever you get any click on this view you can handle it as follows

```
-(void)showMaskView{
    if (!viewMaskView) {
        CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - yourPicker.frame.size.height);
        viewMaskView = [[MaskView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
        viewMaskView.delegate = self;
    }   
    [self.view addSubview:viewMaskView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewMaskView];
}

-(void)removeMaskView{
    if (viewMaskView) {
        [viewMaskView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //Remove the Picker
}
```

In the MaskView class you can handle the touch as follows

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(removeMaskView)])
        [self.delegate removeMaskView];
}
```

you can see the colored mask view over the Picker in the image. When tapped it removes picker.
[image]